# Capitalize the title in Angular

Tags: css, angular

I'm new to Angular, and I need some help with this piece of code:

```html
<ng-template #ballOutOfPlay>
    <h1 class="event_title" [innerHTML]="eventService.currentStat ?.data.text" ></h1>
</ng-template>
```

Here is the string stored in the variable I'm displaying (which is the one I want to capitalize):

```js
eventService.currentStat.data.text = '<p>Ball out of match</p>'
```

I tried the following thing, but it didn't work, btw I can't take away the < p > tag:

```html
<ng-template #ballOutOfPlay>
    <h1 class="event_title" *ngIf="eventService.currentStat && eventService.currentStat.data.text === '<p>Ball out of play</p>'" >
            {{ eventService.currentStat.data.text | upperCase }}
          </h1>
</ng-template>
```

Comment: Why not just `text-transform: uppercase;` for class `event_title`?

Comment: "I tried the following thing, but it didn't work": What did it do? Did it throw an error?

Comment: @dfsq thank you I didn't know that property exists, but that's what I'm going for. otherwise is there a way I can do it using angular?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are using `uppercase` in camel case, try it with all small

```
 {{ eventService.currentStat.data.text | uppercase }}
```

Comment: I tried both but it doesn't work, I get as an output the whole string, with the P tags, while all I want is what's inside of them

Comment: your `eventService.currentStat.data.text` contain `html` tag, remove `<p></p>` from it and print your data like this `<h1 class="event_title" *ngIf="eventService.currentStat && eventService.currentStat.data.text === 'Ball out of play'" >
            <p> {{ eventService.currentStat.data.text | upperCase }} </p>
          </h1>

Comment: That's exactly what I don't want to do as I mentioned in my post : I want to keep the p tags

Comment: then give class in your `<p></p>` and define `style property capitalize` in your css for that class. `<p class="resultDiv" >'Ball out of play</p>` and in css file `text-transform: capitalize` for that clas

Comment: Great :) , if your problem is resolved than mark it as answered